# matching parts of reg

Tags: c#, regex

I am attempting to parse with regex a series of lines of psudeo-assembly code that are the following formats:

```
optional_label  required_instruction    optional_parameter, optional_parameter
```

And actual example looks a bit more like:

```
PRINTLOOP   MOV R6, R7
CMP R6, R9
TRP 1
BLK
```

Where MOV,CMP,BLK and BRZ are instructions.

Whitespace between tokens can be any number of spaces or tabs, labels must start at the beginning of a line while instructions can either start at the beginning or have any amount of leading spaces or tabs.

I need to get at each bit of it individually so it is important that the regex groups it properly. I am currently trying to use this pattern:

```
    ((?<label>[\w]*)[ |\t]+)?(?<operator>[\w]+)[ |\t]+(?<operand1>[\w]+)?(,[ |\t]*(?<openparen>\()?(?<operand2>[-]*[\w]+)(?<closeparen>\))?)?
```

This pattern has worked fine until now because there was always at least one parameter, but now I have zero parameter instructions which don't fit in nicely to this. I tried to tweak the pattern to be the following:

```
    ((?<label>[\w]*)[ |\t]+)?(?<operator>[\w]+)([ |\t]+(?<operand1>[\w]+))?(,[ |\t]*(?<openparen>\()?(?<operand2>[-]*[\w]+)(?<closeparen>\))?)?
```

So that the space after the instruction(operator) isn't mandatory but I found that this made things ambiguous enough that the instruction is perceived to be the label in many instructions. For example:

```
    LDB     R0,      lM
```

Is understood as label: LDB, Instruction: R0 and neither operand is recognized.

Is their a way to either force the operator section to be checked first (so that that part of the string is prioritized), resources that will explain where I am going wrong in all this, or a regex pattern that will do what I am looking for?

Comment: Splitting on spaces would be much easier in this case

Comment: @BlackBear I have considered that but I need the regex regardless I think.This is for an assembler I am writing and it needs to recognize  instructions lines (to allocate space for them). So I was trying to kill 2 birds with one stone. I may yet come back to that.

Comment: @BlackBear It wouldn't work either, because the grammar is ambiguous.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight not really, I did it and it wasn't that hard. I basically did like you suggested in your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem cannot be solved even in theory, because your grammar is ambiguous: when you are looking at

```
INC R6
```

your grammar can parse it in the two ways below:

```
label=INC, Instruction=R6
```

or

```
Instruction=R6, Parameter1=R6
```

Assembly languages that I've worked with and/or implemented solve this problem by requiring a column after the optional label, like this:

```
[label:]  instruction [parameter] [, optional_parameter]
```

This would give your regex an additional "anchor" (i.e. the colon `:`) by which to tell the label+instruction vs. instruction+parameter situation.

Another alternative is to introduce "keywords" for the instructions, and prohibiting the use of these keywords as labels. This would let you avoid introducing a colon, but would make a regex-based solution impractical.